# Import JPA interfaces

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to import JPA's interfaces without linking the provider's libs?
I'm trying to build my system's persistence interfaces and adapters to allow a modular persistence layer, but in order to do so I must link Hibernate's (or some other JPA provider) jars.
To my understanding, the JPA interfaces are not provided with the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You include **persistence-api.jar** to compile against. Sadly the people behind JPA decided not to bother publishing v2.0 of that jar into a Maven repository so you have to rely on the various versions of jars providing this. For example EclipseLink has a persistence-api.jar, as does Hibernate, and there is also an Apache licensed "Geronimo Specs JPA 2.0 jar" providing the same *"javax.persistence"* classes.

Comment: I guess it's not a "cross-provider" jar

Comment: all of those jars provide javax.persistence so you can use any with any provider